# Type mismatch error in custom jpa query with 'like' operator

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa

I'm trying to write such select (it works from console)

```
select * from orders o where (o.id like '%1%')
```

with

```
@Query("SELECT o from Order o where o.id like %:searchQuery%")
Page<Order> findAllBySearchQuery(Long searchQuery, Pageable pageable);
```

but IDEA shows that o.id has `Type mismatch: string type expected` and when I try to call the method I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [%1%] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)]`,
I can't find solution for this. I found only how to do it with `nativeQuery = true`, but it doesn't support `Pageable`.

Type of id is bigint. MariaDB.

Comment: Note that having the need to compare an integer column against a text like expression probably implies poor database design.

Comment: I'm trying to compare long value with value in db from bigint column. Issue is I need to get all numbers that includes searching value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct approach here to bind a string to the placeholder which already contains the wildcards:

```
@Query("SELECT o from Order o where o.id like :searchQuery")
Page<Order> findAllBySearchQuery(String searchQuery, Pageable pageable);
```

When using `findAllBySearchQuery`, you should bind to `searchQuery` something like `%10%`, assuming you wanted to find any `id` which contained the number 10.  For example, call:

```
findAllbySearchQuery("%10%", somePageable);
```

There is another potential issue here, namely the type of `Order#id`, and the corresponding type in the actual SQL table.  Ideally, it should be text as well, otherwise it does not make sense trying to compare text against a number.

**Edit:** Given that you have revealed your `id` column to be an integer, you may try first casting it to text before doing the like comparison:

```
@Query("SELECT o from Order o where cast(o.id as string) like :searchQuery")
Page<Order> findAllBySearchQuery(String searchQuery, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Still nothing changes.

Comment: What is the type of `id`?  What is your database?  On many SQL databases, you _can't_ compare text against a number.

Comment: Type of id is `bigint`, MariaDB. But I can compare it with `select * from orders o where (o.id like '%1%')` and everything works. From console.

Comment: @Konstantin Try the second version in my updated answer.

Comment: IDEA underlines bracket after 'cast' and writes `<expression>, <operator>, GROUP, HAVING or ORDER expected, got '('`. But it works. Somehow. I still don't understand why it works in console without any casting.

Comment: @Konstantin Actually, on most other databases besides MySQL/MariaDB, it would not even work from the console.  As I have mentioned already, you are trying to compare text against an integer column.  Something was probably happening from within Hibernate which was preventing the explicit cast from happening correctly.  Best practice would be to not do this comparison at all, and fix your database design.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Maybe I don't see better solution. I need to make query which returns all id's that includes some number. For example 123, 32, 2, for 2. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: It seems like a strange requirement, but in this case maybe the query is justified, or maybe the `id` column should be text (assuming it doesn't need to be auto increment).